C++ Concurrency in Action threadsafe_stack question, undefined reference to `vtable for empty_stack'
I tried to implement the threadsafe_stack in C++ Concurrency in Action chapter 3, and when I tried to use it in main.cpp with two thread, I got error message: undefined reference to `vtable for empty_stack', it happened when i tried to use pop() member function. I don't understand why, could anyone give some help?
Here is codes
Threadsafe_stack.h
#include <exception>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <stack>

struct empty_stack: std::exception {
  const char* what() const throw();
};

template<typename T>
class Threadsafe_stack {
private:
  
  std::stack<T> data;
  mutable std::mutex m;

public:
  Threadsafe_stack() {}
  ~Threadsafe_stack() {}

  //copy constructor
  Threadsafe_stack(const Threadsafe_stack& other) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(other.m);
    data = other.data;
  }

  //delete assign operator
  Threadsafe_stack& operator=(const Threadsafe_stack&) = delete;

  void push(T new_val) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    data.push(std::move(new_val));
  }

  std::shared_ptr<T> pop() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty()) {
      throw empty_stack();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(data.top()));
    data.pop();
    return res;
  }

  void pop(T& val) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if (data.empty()) {
      throw empty_stack();
    }

    val = data.top();
    data.pop();
  }

  bool empty() const {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    return data.empty();
  }

};

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "Threadsafe_stack.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  Threadsafe_stack<int> ts_stack;
  
  
  std::thread t1([&ts_stack]() {
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
      ts_stack.push(i);
      std::cout << "t1 pushed: " << i << "\n";
    }

  });

  std::thread t2([&ts_stack]() {
  
    for (int i = 11; i <= 20; ++i) {
      ts_stack.push(i);
      std::cout << "t2 pushed: " << i << "\n";
    }
  });
  

  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  
  //error here
  int val;
  ts_stack.pop(val);
  std::cout << "poped: " << val << "\n";

  //error here
  /*
  while (!ts_stack.empty()) {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = ts_stack.pop();
    std::cout << "t2 poped: " << ptr.get() << "\n";
  }
  */

  return 0;
}

project structure
├── ch3
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Threadsafe_stack.h
│
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp


Where is your empty_stack::what implementation?

Where do you define const char* what() const throw()?

at the top of Threadsafe_stack.h, copy from the example on the book

No, that's a declaration, not a definition

I guest I did not do it, could you give some examples?

struct empty_stack : std::exception { const char* what() const noexcept override { return "empty_stack"; } }; would work...

thank you!! I just too naive, did not know I should implement it.

@dandelion You're welcome. Note: It looks like you are copying pre C++11 code. what() is noexcept since C++11. it was throw() pre C++11.

Thanks, I checked https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what, too. A detail I should remember!
